# Spanning columns [HTML]

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm developing a hybrid-app w/ Cordova. In my `index.html` I have the following code:

```
<div class="container">
<table style="width:100%;height:100%;border-spacing:3px;border-collapse: separate;">
    <tr style="height:15%;width:100%">
        <td style="width:33%">
            <button class="btn btn-default" style="width:100%" type="button">OK</button>
        </td>
        &nbsp;
        <td style="width:33%">
            <button class="btn btn-default" style="width:100%" type="button">OK</button>
        </td>
        &nbsp;
        <td style="width:33%" colspan="3">
            <button class="btn btn-default" style="width:100%" type="button">OK</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height:15%;width:100%">
        <td style="width:25%">
            <button class="btn btn-default"style="width:100%" type="button">OK</button>
        </td>
        <td style="width:25%">
            <button class="btn btn-default" style="width:100%"type="button">OK</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-default" style="width:100%"type="button">OK</button>
        </td>

        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-default" style="width:100%"type="button">OK</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Don't care about the Bootstrap things, the main thing is the `<td>` tags in the second `<tr>`.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Same here, no idea what the question is. First of all, you don't have a closing `</div>` for your container, and there's `&nbsp;` in between your table cells which shouldn't be there.

Comment: Your code seems to work decently: https://jsfiddle.net/npe0Lfh6/1/

Comment: Last `<td>` in first row should be `<td .... colspan="2">`

Comment: @s1h4d0w i forgot to copy over the `</div>`, my bad
@GeneR I first did that and it didn't work :(

Comment: plus, I don't want it to be like [this] (http://imgur.com/tQhMAD2) but instead like [this] (https://jsfiddle.net/npe0Lfh6/1/)

Comment: I see no difference between those 2.

Comment: @takendarkk there are 2 distinct `<table>`s with 1 row instead of one table with two rows

Comment: How are we supposed to see that from a screenshot? Post code, not images.

Comment: the code is in the first post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, this is what I wanted. I figured it out :)

```html
<div class="container">
    <table style="width:100%;height:100%;border-spacing:3px;border-collapse: separate;">
        <tr style="height:15%;width:100%">
            <td style="width:33%">
                <button class="btn btn-default" style="width:100%" type="button">OK</button>
            </td>
            <td style="width:33%">
                <button class="btn btn-default" style="width:100%" type="button">OK</button>
            </td>
            <td style="width:33%" >
                <button class="btn btn-default" style="width:100%" type="button">OK</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr style="height:15%;width:100%">
            <td style="width:25%">
                <button class="btn btn-default" style="width:100%" type="button">OK</button>
            </td>
            <td style="width:25%">
                <button class="btn btn-default" style="width:100%" type="button">OK</button>
            </td>
            <td style="width:25%">
                <button class="btn btn-default" style="width:100%" type="button">OK</button>
            </td>

            <td style="width:25%">
                <button class="btn btn-default" style="width:100%" type="button">OK</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your 1:st `tr`'s last `td`'s to `<td style="width:33%" colspan="2">` and both rows will be equal wide.

```html
<div class="container">
  <table style="width:100%;height:100%;border-spacing:3px;border-collapse: separate;">
  
    <tr style="height:15%;width:100%">
      <td style="width:33%">
        <button class="btn btn-default" style="width:100%" type="button">OK</button>
      </td>
      <td style="width:33%">
        <button class="btn btn-default" style="width:100%" type="button">OK</button>
      </td>
      <td style="width:33%" colspan="2">
        <button class="btn btn-default" style="width:100%" type="button">OK</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr style="height:15%;width:100%">
      <td style="width:25%">
        <button class="btn btn-default" style="width:100%" type="button">OK</button>
      </td>
      <td style="width:25%">
        <button class="btn btn-default" style="width:100%" type="button">OK</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-default" style="width:100%" type="button">OK</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-default" style="width:100%" type="button">OK</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, I finally see what he meant. Good answer!